# How to monitor and avoid over-filling a message queue (posix)

Tags: posix, message-queue

I'm trying to avoid overfilling the message queue so here are few questions I have

When using **mq_attr**

1. When is **mq_curmsgs** full? when it's 0 or max_msgs
2. When it's full, do i need to flush it?
3. Would you recommend to use any of these: **select**, **poll** or **epoll**? if so how do i use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) mq_curmsgs == mq_maxmsg is full

(2) Only if you want to continue to write to it.  What's the point of putting things in a queue if you never read it?  If you are asking if you can alternatively expand the queue on the fly rather than read it then no.  The queue limits are specified when it is created.

(3) Depends on what you are doing.  Your alternatives for reading the queue basically come down to these:

1. `mq_receive` will block by default.
2. The queue can be opened as nonblocking with `mq_open` or changed to nonblocking with `mq_setattr`.  The gives you a basic polling capability to see if there is currently something to read.
3. You can use `mq_notify`.  This allows you specify that either (a) a signal or (b) a thread be spawned whenever *an empty queue* gets a new message.
4. You can use `mq_timedreceive`.  This, if the queue in blocking mode, will only block for the length of time you specify.
5. You can use `select`, etc., under linux because the mqd_t type is a file descriptor.  This might not be true of other POSIX systems.  `select` and brothers provide you with the capability of multiplexing your queue(s) with other i/o events and be informed of when there is something in the queue to be read.